# Arduino Leonardo si4703

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to set up SI4703 breakout board with an arduino leonardo compatible board. I'm using Sparkfun Lib and my sketch is:

```
#include <Si4703_Breakout.h>
#include <Wire.h>

int resetPin = 4;
int SDIO = 2;
int SCLK = 3;

Si4703_Breakout radio(resetPin, SDIO, SCLK);
int channel;
int volume;
char rdsBuffer[10];

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial){

  }
  Serial.println("\n\nSi4703_Breakout Test Sketch");
  Serial.println("===========================");  
  Serial.println("a b     Favourite stations");
  Serial.println("+ -     Volume (max 15)");
  Serial.println("u d     Seek up / down");
  Serial.println("r       Listen for RDS Data (15 sec timeout)");
  Serial.println("Send me a command letter.");


  radio.powerOn();
  radio.setVolume(0);
}

void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available())
  {
    char ch = Serial.read();
    if (ch == 'u') 
    {
      channel = radio.seekUp();
      displayInfo();
    } 
    else if (ch == 'd') 
    {
      channel = radio.seekDown();
      displayInfo();
    } 
    else if (ch == '+') 
    {
      volume ++;
      if (volume == 16) volume = 15;
      radio.setVolume(volume);
      displayInfo();
    } 
    else if (ch == '-') 
    {
      volume --;
      if (volume < 0) volume = 0;
      radio.setVolume(volume);
      displayInfo();
    } 
    else if (ch == 'a')
    {
      channel = 930; // Rock FM
      radio.setChannel(channel);
      displayInfo();
    }
    else if (ch == 'b')
    {
      channel = 974; // BBC R4
      radio.setChannel(channel);
      displayInfo();
    }
    else if (ch == 'r')
    {
      Serial.println("RDS listening");
      radio.readRDS(rdsBuffer, 15000);
      Serial.print("RDS heard:");
      Serial.println(rdsBuffer);      
    }
  }
}

void displayInfo()
{
   Serial.print("Channel:"); Serial.print(channel); 
   Serial.print(" Volume:"); Serial.println(volume); 
}
```

I've made the changes to SDIO, SCLK and resetPin according to my board from [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/wire) but when I start the serial monitor and after I input some commands it freezes until I restart from board. Furthermore my commands do nothing. Any ideas?

[Here's a picture from the stuck serial monitor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13P2v.png)

Comment: What's `while(!Serial){

  }` supposed to do?

Comment: It just waits for the computer to open the serial port. [Look here](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/4556/what-does-the-line-while-serial-do-in-an-arduino-program)

Comment: Ah, it's one of those Leonardo quirks; USB-related stuff